# ffmpeg causes browser to hang up?

Tags: browser, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to convert videos on the fly, as they say, and I'm facing with a very annoying, unsolvable and unreferenced problem (as of yet ;) ), when I run my php script, it basically works - takes the file, uses ffmpeg, starts converting it, but halway through it's finished, the browser hangs, I don't understand why or how to resolve it:
(even with set_time_limit the bastard won't work).

```
function convertToMp4(){
    /*
     * Converts a file to mp4, returns the new file name
     */
    set_time_limit(0);
    $tmpFile = $this->fileName;
    $newFile = uniqid();
    $outputFile = "output/$justFile.mp4";
    exec("ffmpeg -i " . $tmpFile . " -acodec copy -ar 44100 -ab 96k " . $outputFile. " &");
    unlink($tmpFile);
    return $outputFile;
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after much frustration, I realized that because ffmpeg takes a while to process, it's a regular browser time out...
if you really need to encode large files, you should use cron jobs to start the encoding, but don't expect to finish it in due time...

Answer (score 0):

what version of ffmpeg is being used? [this forum thread](http://themetabrowser.com/boards/2/topics/4155) seems to talk about the same issue, and it's fairly recently been modified. They suggest the latest version of ffmpeg:

> Added by fatal 27 days ago
>
> Hey,
>
> That is the exact command being run so I do not know why it is hanging
>   your system as I also have a 10sec timeout for the process which
>   should self terminate incase of a hang.
>
> I just tried with their latest version:
>
> ffmpeg version N-33818-gd049257, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg
>   developers built on Oct 19 2011 23:01:30 with gcc 4.6.1
>
> and it worked as expected.
>
> At what point in metabrowser does it freeze? Does it show the seconds
>   bar with the second it is going to next to it?
>
> Take Care